# Good Samaritan Luke's Gospel - Chronology, Geography

Tags: luke, chronology, geography

I'm currently studying the parable of the Good Samaritan, and I'm wondering why it was chronologically placed in Luke 10 which seems to indicate the encounter with the expert in the law occurred before Jesus entered Jerusalem as king.

The question asked by the expert in the law is "What must I do to inherit eternal life?" and Jesus asks him what his interpretation of scripture is.

The expert replies - "Love the Lord your God with all your heart and with all your soul and with all your strength and with all your mind; and "Love your neighbour as yourself".

This is the same answer Jesus gave when asked what the greatest commandment was (Matthew 22:35–40 and Mark 12:28–34).

It seems to me there is a connection between the two stories.

In my mind I'd always thought Jesus was the one who originally summed up the whole of the Law in this way.

It makes more sense to me that the parable of the Good Samaritan should sit somewhere in Luke 20 when the authority of Jesus is questioned. It would line up with Mathew and Mark better.

Otherwise are we to assume that Jesus was quoting the expert when he gives his answer in Mathew and Mark?

Doesn't it make more sense that the expert in the law in Luke's good Samaritan had heard Jesus sum the law up in this way - but he wanted more clarification as to who his neighbour was... Therefore the encounter in Luke is more likely to have taken place in Jerusalem?

Or am I simply wrong in thinking there is a connection between these accounts?

Comment: I would say that just because Luke placed the story earlier in his book does not mean it occurred chronologically in that order. Luke is very often non-contiguous in his writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two stories in Luke 10 are perfectly placed as they are definitely connected.

In the account of the lawyer, you will notice in verse 25 that the lawyer asks the question in order to “tempt” (or test) Jesus. This tells you that the lawyer has heard His teaching on grace (thinking it contradicted the law) and now wanted to test Him.

> 5 And, behold, a certain lawyer stood up, and tempted him, saying,
>   Master, what shall I do to inherit eternal life?

Jesus fully understands this however, answers along the lines of the OT covenant of the law.

> 26 He said unto him, What is written in the law? how readest thou?

This response now “sets up” the lawyer as Christ already knows how he will respond.

> 27 And he answering said, Thou shalt love the Lord thy God with all
>   thy heart, and with all thy soul, and with all thy strength, and with
>   all thy mind; and thy neighbour as thyself.
>   28 And he said unto him, Thou hast answered right: this do, and thou
>   shalt live.

Jesus repsonds per the law and just tells him to go and do it. However, the lawyer, not satisfied with the answer (since he was testing Jesus) and wanting to “justify himself” says:

> 29 But he, willing to justify himself, said unto Jesus, And who is my
>   neighbour?

At that point Jesus has got him. The Pharisess were notorious for favoring the wealthy and prosperous and avoiding the less fortunate. They believed that prosperity was a sign of blessing by God and negative life circumstances were due to your sin (see the story of the blind man in John 9). So the lawyer, wanting to justify himself (since he most likely only loved his “affluent” neighbors) now wants to be vindicated in his “law abiding” actions.

Jesus then launches into the story of the Good Samaritan.

In the story you will notice, the first two men who pass the beaten man, were a priest and a Levite. This is purposeful for the lawyer would naturally place himself squarely in the story as one of these two who “attempted” to keep the law. Both fail to lend assistance due to requirements within the Law of Moses.

According to Numbers 19:11, any person who touches a dead person is deemed as defiled for seven days.

Numbers 19: 11 (KJV):

> 11 He that toucheth the dead body of any man shall be unclean seven
>   days.

If you are defiled, there is a purification process you must then subject yourself to.  Obviously, the priest and the Levite in not wanting to offend the law (not knowing if the man were dead or alive) pass by on the other side. In addition, the priest and the Levite would have held that the beaten man most likely had some kind of sin in his life and that is why he found himself in this situation. Again, affluence was seen as a blessing of God and negative circumstances were seen as a curse of God.

Jesus then places a Samaritan as the hero in the story.  The Samaritans were not only hated by the Jews but the Jews excluded them from the kingdom of God for their worship on Mt. Gerizim and not the temple mount. This was a huge contradiction for the lawyer. For here is a person outside the kingdom of God, completely ignoring the Law of Moses, who extends mercy to the beaten man and obviously becomes his neighbor in Christ’s story.

The lawyer answers the obvious question of “who was his neighbor” correctly, however we don’t know if it was because of embarrassment or if he really understood the principal of “mercy triumphs over judgment” (James 2).

All verses KJV.

Comment: thanks alb - as well as understanding the parable I'm trying to place it in context, chronologically and geographically.  It would seems Luke is suggesting this was something that took place before the triumphant entry.  But when Jesus taught the greatest commandment in (Matthew 22:35–40 and Mark 12:28–34) this was after.  Is it possible that the expert in the law had summed up the whole of the law so wisely that Jesus was repeating him?  Isn't it more likely that the good Samaritan story took place later and the expert in the Law was quoting Jesus - telling him what he knew he wanted to hear?

Comment: Sorry, you did ask that in your question; pardon my poor reading. In reviewing the 2 stories, I don’t think they are related other than the Pharisees/Saducees were trying to test Him in both cases. You can’t assume Jesus quotes the lawyer just because the lawyer’s similar words are recorded before Jesus’ entry into Jerusalem. Jesus taught this premise prior to His entry into Jerusalem. (con’t)

Comment: In Matthew 19:19 He says: “Thou shalt love thy neighbour as thyself” as part of a list of commandments. Chronologically, this is about the same time as the lawyer’s question in Luke 10. Matthew 17 records the transfiguration (same as Luke 9). Matthew 18 records the disciples asking “who is the greatest” (same as Luke 9). This would put Matthew 19 around the same time as Luke 10.  So, we see that Christ taught the same principals which could have prompted the lawyer in Luke 10 to respond the way he did.

Comment: One more thought: it's not probable that the lawyer was giving Jesus what He wanted to hear since they were trying to test Him and catch Him in a contradiction. They would have challenged Him, not placate Him.